# Dlib options from .dat file

Tags: python, c++, dlib

Is it possible to get options, from a .dat file of Dlib shape predictor? I have trained a good predictor but forgot to print the options from it and now I can't reproduce the results.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no such possibility. As you can see in the [documentation](http://dlib.net/python/index.html#dlib.shape_predictor), the shape predictor class only has the following methods:

- predict shape ('call')
- constructor / create instance ('init')
- save model ('save')